# Getting weird error with the function as.ggplot() from ggplotify package

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics, package

This uses the library ggplotify. This allows me to take a base r plot and create a ggplot plot from it with the function `as.ggplot()`.
However, I am receiving an error that doesn't make sense to me when I run the following lines of code.

```
y <- 1:10
x <- 2:11
length(x)
length(y)
as.ggplot(~plot(x, y))
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
'x' and 'y' lengths differ.
```

However, `x` and `y` have the same length and when I use `plot(x,y)` normally, I don't receive any errors. Can someone please explain this to me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when you put the values directly in the function:

```
as.ggplot(~plot(1:10,2:11))
```

I think it is just limited to working like this.